# Why is my Broadcast Receiver not get system broadcast actions?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When specifying a BroadcastReceiver in the manifest, I am receiving none of the following system actions:

```
public class BRMemoryHandler extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public BRMemoryHandler()
    {
        Log.d("BRMH", "ctor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Log.d("BRMH", "onReceive()");
    }
}

<application
    android:name="Test"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

    <receiver android:name=".BRMemoryHandler" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_OK" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

However, I am able to receive this actions if I create the same Broadcast Receiver programmatically in my main activity:

```
void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(Bundle b);

    BRMemoryHandler tbr = new BRMemoryHandler();

    IntentFilter intF = new IntentFilter();
    intF.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    intF.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);

    registerReceiver(tbr, intF);
```

Comment: Check this https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/bQ3ambT0LI8/0fS0bUQ-w6kJ

Comment: This post doesn't help because it doesn't mention the problem of not receiving actions with a BR configured in the manifest.

Comment: The only thing it does is explain the cause of the problem: **...sends out this intent with its FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY flag set...** - so it works when you register receiver and doesn't work for your receiver declared in manifest.

Comment: Ahh, you're right! This is unfortunate because what I really need is a notification of ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW. So how does one know, without digging into the code, that an intent is FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY? This is an important piece of info.

Comment: Good question, I have no idea. I recently ran into a similar issue with `android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON`. Nothing in the documentation also, only sources helped.